# Batch File -resultfile is invalid

Tags: batch-file

We have an older project that it was determined should have a new unit test project as the old one was severely out of date and had not been used in a long time. We have the new unit test project set up with one file with a handful of tests in it. We are now setting up a batch file to generate some information to be used by Jenkins. I have never done this before but we had the batch file from the old unit test project so i am modifying it to try and get it to spit out the same documents as before. Everything seems to work if I remove the -resultsfile aregumet (under the comment "Run OpenCover on all unit test dlls" so I know that -resultsfile should be the issue. in the console when i run the batch file with -resultsfile in place i get the following in red "The argument -resultsfile:UnitTests\CodeCoverageUnitTest.trx is invalid."

Here is the entirety of the batch file:

```
@echo off
rem --- Run Unit Tests ---
rem --- Set working directory ---
SET mypath=%~dp0
pushd %mypath:~0,-1%%
echo OutputPath : "%mypath:~0,-1%\UnitTests\bin\VRI_Web_UnifiedAPI_Test2\VRI_Web_UnifiedAPI_Test2.csproj"

rem --- Clean up previous tests ---
if exist "TestResults" rd /s /q "TestResults"
if exist "UnitTests" rd /s /q "UnitTests"
if not exist "UnitTests" (
    mkdir "UnitTests"
)
if not exist "UnitTests\bin" (
    mkdir "UnitTests\bin"
)

rem --- Build unit test csproj projects ---
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /p:WarningLevel=0 /t:Rebuild /verbosity:minimal /p:OutputPath="%mypath:~0,-1%\UnitTests\bin\VRI_Web_UnifiedAPI_Test2"


rem --- Run OpenCover on all unit test dlls ---
  ..\..\Third_Party\Microsoft\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -register -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"\"UnitTests\bin\VRI_Web_UnifiedAPI_Test2\VRI.Web.UnifiedAPI.Test2.dll\" -resultsfile:\"UnitTests/CodeCoverageUnitTest.trx\" -filter:\"+[VRI.Web.UnifiedAPI.Models.TH]*\" \"-[VRI.Web.UnifiedAPI.Test]*\" -excludebyattribute:\"*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage*\"^" -mergebyhash -output:"UnitTests/codecoveragereport.xml"


rem --- Run ReportGenerator all Open Cover output ---
"..\..\Third_Party\Microsoft\ReportGenerator.2.5.1\tools\ReportGenerator.exe" -reports:"UnitTests\codecoveragereport.xml" -targetdir:"UnitTests\CodeCoverage"

rem --- Run OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter to create a report Jenkins can use ---
"..\..\Third_Party\Microsoft\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.0.2.4.0\tools\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe" -input:"UnitTests\codecoveragereport.xml" -output:"UnitTests\cobertura.xml"
```

I have tried changing the / to \ in the path. I tried creating the file with a null value prior to running the command that has the -resultsfile . I can't find anything on google as to what the issue might be and i tried asking chat gpt but it only tells me things i have already tried.

Comment: Your argument is `-resultsfile:\"UnitTests/CodeCoverageUnitTest.trx\"` The terminal backslash makes the "filename" a directoryname. Correcting `/` to backslash is desirable as `/` is a switch-indicator. You appear to be attempting to use backslash as an escape character. The quotes are quite legitimate - they tell `cmd` that the string (between a pair of quotes) is a single token & thus the quotes do not need an escape, in fact a leading backslash indicates that the file/directoryname is on the root directory of the current drive. [theory only - I have no knowledge of `OpenCover.Console.exe`]